# iOS Auto Layout - Keep two views (grouped) centered in superview, content changes dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I hope this question will be easy answered by you geniuses out there.

I have a view with two subviews: an UIImageView and an UILabel. The image view will remain the same, but the label text content will change dynamically. I'm just getting started with auto layout so no much experience with it. I want the two subviews to always look like they are grouped and that the "group" is centered both H and V within its superview, regardless of label's content:

`+------------------------------------------+
|                                          |
|           +-----+ +----------+           |
|           | Img | | ShortText|           |
|           +-----+ +----------+           |
|                                          |
+------------------------------------------+`

`+------------------------------------------+
|                                          |
|       +-----+ +-------------------+      |
|       | Img | |    LongText       |      |
|       +-----+ +-------------------+      |
|                                          |
+------------------------------------------+`

I'm not sure of what's the best way to approach this. So far I added the two subviews into a "placeholder" invisible view (let's call it groupView) and added constraints to center it within the superview. It works ok with the initial label text, but when the text starts changing, the groupView origin remains fixed and doesn't get centered.

This is the code:

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
UIView *groupView = [[UIView alloc] init];
groupView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]];
imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[groupView addSubview:imgView];
titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
titleLabel.text = @"Title";
[groupView addSubview:titleLabel];
[containerView addSubview:groupView];

NSDictionary *viewDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(containerView, groupView, imgView, titleLabel);
[groupView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:groupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
[groupView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[imgView]-[titleLabel]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
[containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:groupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
[containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:groupView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can specify width and height for imageView, height for contentView and label, horizontal spaces for label. And in addition increase labels' hugging priority. So, label width will increase due to its' intrinsic size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually the fix was very simple. When setting constraints to align the image view and the label, I forgot to include the superview symbol (`|`) in the VFL string, therefore (I think) groupView didn't calculate correctly its intrinsic size.

Changing it like this:

```
[groupView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[imgView]-[titleLabel]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
```

and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one...

```
 UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[containerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"120.png"]];
imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[containerView addSubview:imgView];

titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
titleLabel.text = @"Title1";
[containerView addSubview:titleLabel];

[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

One container in that one image and text will add according to the image size and text size
First I have added Constraints for the inner view so its superview(containerView) I have added Constraints in that

```
 id innerView=@{@"image":imgView,@"lable":titleLabel};
  [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[image]-5-[lable]-5-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:innerView]];
   [containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[image]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:innerView]];
```

Horitantal Constraints : First Superview (|)-ImageView[image]- 5 px margin - lable[lable] - 5 pix margin- Superview(|)

Vertical Constraint : SuperView - 5 [top marigin] -[image] - 5 [margin] - [superview]

Now add Constraints for the containerView add this to that superview(self.view)

```
  id logoV=@{@"containerView":containerView};
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[containerView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:logoV]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

Vertical Constraints: - superview - 20 [margin] - [containerView]

Horizontal Constraints: its center of the X